# PHP Function to get First 5 Values of array

Tags: php, arrays, slice

```
Array
(
    [university] => 57
    [iit] => 57
    [jee] => 44
    [application] => 28
    [study] => 26
    [college] => 23
    [exam] => 19
    [colleges] => 19
    [view] => 19
    [amp] => 18
)
```

How can I get an array with the first 5 elements?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use [`array_slice()`](http://pl.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=array_slice) function:

```
$newArray = array_slice($originalArray, 0, 5, true);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need the first 5 elements

- by order of keys: use [ksort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php),
- by order of values: use [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

before the [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php). Insert a letter *'r'* to the second place for reverse order: [krsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php), [arsort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php).

Comment: Yep, but maybe he means top 5.