# First five max elements in parametric array

Tags: php

I have this parametric array:

```
array[Tour Eiffel] = 0.6225
array[Arc de Triomphe] = 0.85
array[Avenue des Champs-Elysees] = 0.28
array[Place de la Concorde] = 0.3425
array[Palais Garnier] = 0.5025
array[Galeries Lafayette] = 0.35
array[Moulin Rouge] = 0.5425
array[Louvre] = 0.9425
array[Centre Pompidou] = 0.4425
array[Eglise Saint-Eustache] = 0.5825
```

I want to find in order the first five max elements and print the results how belows:

```
Louvre is 0.9425
Arc de Triomphe is 0.85
Tour Eiffel is 0.6225
Eglise Saint-Eustache is 0.5825
Moulin Rouge is 0.5425
```

I have used the function max() but this return only the max value and without the parametric key (example Louvre).

Comment: Why -1 vote for this post?

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted but I upvoted you back only because i hate anon downvotes. In the future perhaps discuss what you have done already, some people are big on that here.

Comment: @JGallardo only upvote if you truly believe the title attribute on the up arrow to be reflective of the question:  "This question shows research effort; it is useful and clear"

Comment: @danronmoon yes they showed effort. But I was more apt to upvote when some random user downvotes a question that shows effort and does not explain their vote as that just discourages new users.

Comment: I didn't downvote but it could come down to the lack of searching.  Searching 'First five max elements in array php' in Google gave me this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563958/php-function-to-get-first-5-values-of-array.  The last answer to that question is the right one here.  Always a subjective topic but asking here should be a last resort.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arsort($array);    // sort array in reverse order
$top_vals = array_slice($array, 0, 5, true);  // taking first 5 elements preserving keys
foreach ($top_vals as $k => $v)
    echo $k . ' is ' . $v . '<br />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to sort an array in reverse order and maintain index association

```
arsort($arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

$count = 0;
foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
   echo "$key is $val";
   $count += 1;
   if ($count === 5) {
       break;
   }
   echo '<br />';
}
```